# Letter 'd' gets types continuously without me typing and then my touchpad stops working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

This was not happening for the first two days after installing Ubuntu..
I tried reinstalling but the problem is still there

Comment: This seems like a hardware issue. The very first thing you should do is take the cap off the D key and clean it.

Comment: Yup I saw to it. Had to take a closer look under my keyboard keys. The 'd' key is still super sensitive but I have placed a piece of folded paper between the rubber and the membrane now and it seems to work fine for now.

Comment: It still types 3-4 times 'd' but that's something I need to bear with till I get a new keyboard.